# Bucle for con dos condiciones

Tags: php, bucle-for

Muy buenas a todos..

¿Cuál es la lógica de un ciclo for con dos condiciones, es decir, como se interpreta?¿ambas condiciones deben cumplirse si o si o funcionan de manera independientes?

les pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
for ($i=0, $j=0; $i < count($valori), $j < count($valorj); $i++, $j++) {
//code...
}
```

Actualizo:
Debo aclarar que he trabajado con php y me ha funcionado, no genera errores, se puede hacer con operadores lógicos también(AND, OR) y funciona bien, más abajo ya respondieron la pregunta, gracias por leer.

PD: las etiquetas las puse para saber si en aquellos lenguajes existe algo así, y de ser así de que manera se entendía, en php funciona.

Comment: Por favor edita y limita el uso de etiquetas colocando solo aquellas directamente relacionadas

Comment: ese for en python no existe, no? en c# y java con esos nombres de variables tambien es dudoso no? podrias especificar bien el lenguaje que estas usando, y lo probaste?

Comment: Puedes explicar el ejercicio que quieres hacer, creo pudiera haber otras formas como iterar 1 y después el otro y de ahí sacar una condición

Comment: mmmm...ese formato con 2 condiciones separadas por comas no existen en java no existe

Comment: La verdad puse las etiquetas para ver si en aquellos lenguajes existe tal lógica, estoy trabajando con php y no hay ningún problema en usar un for con dos condiciones, sin embargo, si no se específica con un operador lógico ambas condiciones deben ser true. Prueben por si acaso, quizás si se puede en algunos lenguajes y sólo no lo han intentado, saludos✌️

Comment: si no sabes si existe, entonces no pongas nada e investiga

Comment: Estás equivocado. Este no es un foro; es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Tienes que hacer preguntas específicas sobre código.

Answer (score 2):

La segunda expresión de un FOR debe ser un valor **Booleano**. Si es TRUE el bucle sigue y si es FALSE el bucle se detiene.

Documentacion del tipo de dato **Booleano**: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.boolean.php

Documentacion de FOR: https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.for.php

¿Donde se utilizan los tipos de datos **Booleanos** en PHP?

- Bucles (FOR, WHILE)
- IF
- Operadores ternarios
- Variables tipo **Booleano**
- etc...

En todas ellas la lógica es la misma. Para poner más de una condición es necesario utilizar operadores lógicos (and, or, qor): https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php

Ejemplo:

Si quiero que se cumpla la siguiente condición:

```
Si el alumno se llama "ana" y (Operador lógico AND) el alumno tiene 42 años
```

Se deberá representar de la siguiente forma en PHP:

En bucles:

```
while($nombre_alumno == 'ana' AND $edad_alumno == 42) {}
for($i=1;$nombre_alumno == 'ana' AND $edad_alumno == 42;$i++) {}
```

En un IF:

```
if($nombre_alumno == 'ana' AND $edad_alumno == 42) {}
```

En un operador ternario:

```
$se_cumple_condicion = $nombre_alumno == 'ana' AND $edad_alumno == 42 ? 'si' : 'no';
```

En una variable de tipo **Booleano**:

```
$es_true = $nombre_alumno == 'ana' AND $edad_alumno == 42;
```

Como puedes ver, el código de la condición es exactamente el mismo, solo que se implementa en escenarios diferentes.

Volviendo a tu pregunta, deberías utilizar la misma técnica y reemplazar la coma (que no es ningún operador lógico) por un AND:

```
for ($i=0, $j=0; $i < count($valori) AND $j < count($valorj); $i++, $j++) {
//code...
}
```

Es cierto que en la primera y en la tercera expresión del FOR se utilizan comas, pero estas dos expresiones no son condiciones sino ejecuciones, por lo tanto no funcionan de la misma manera.

Un saludo, espero haber resuelto tus dudas.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por comentar, su explicación se entiende a la perfección!